# Page browsing in typo3 using pi_list_browseresults()

Tags: typo3

I would like to set the number of links to browse the result pages in my 
  extension created with kickstarter. (Page1 Page2 Page3...).

The maximum number can be easily set (in this case to 4):

```
**$this->internal["maxPages"]=t3lib_div::intInRange($lConf["maxPages"],0,1000,4); **
```

But this will show me the first four links all the time, no matter on 
 which page I am. So say I have 7 result pages and I am already on page 
 four: I see "Page1 Page2 Page3 Page4".

Is there a possibilty to change 
 this dynamically.

So on Page 4 I see " Page2 Page3 Page4 Page5"

On Page 5 I see " Page3 Page4 Page5 Page6"
 and so on?

Comment: which typo3 version are you using?

Comment: I am using Typo3 version 4.5.20

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
$this->internal['pagefloat']
```

It is defined like this:

```
Using $this->internal['pagefloat']: this defines were the current page is shown in the 
list of pages in the Pagebrowser. If this var is an integer it will be interpreted as   
position in the list of pages. If its value is the keyword "center" the current page will 
be shown in the middle of the pagelist.
```

You can find more options and description in the doc header of function pi_list_browseresults (class tslib_pibase): 
Line 425, http://doxygen.frozenkiwi.com/typo3/html/de/d1c/class_8tslib__pibase_8php_source.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/extension-modifizieren-neu-erstellen/55721-fe-userlisting.html.
The user has given the code using which he has successfully implemented pagination, like:

............

```
 $this->internal['results_at_a_time'] = t3lib_utility_Math::forceIntegerInRange($lConf['results_at_a_time'], 0, 1000, 3); // Number of results to show in a listing.
 $this->internal['maxPages'] = t3lib_utility_Math::forceIntegerInRange($lConf['maxPages'], 0, 1000, 2); // The maximum number of "pages" in the browse-box: "Page 1", 'Page 2', etc.
```

...........